# What does C modify in "A of B that C"? "A" or "B" or "A of B"? Are there some rules?

Tags: modifiers, subordinate-clauses

I have sentences as follow, I want to know what the "that", "while", and the second "that" subordinate clause modify?

The goal is to find short descriptions **of** the members of a collection **that** enable efficient processing of large collections **while** preserving the essential statistical relationships **that** are useful for basic tasks.

Answer (score 1):

The most confusing is the first **that**, but I believe it refers to "short descriptions". Neither the members nor the collection itself would directly enable efficient processing of that collection, but a short, fitting description would.

**While:** "processing" (so the goal is that processing and preserving both happen at the same time).

**That:** "statistical relationships" (they are useful for basic tasks).